# Verilog: assigning to a module input from within the module itself is okay to do?

Tags: input, module, verilog, assign

I just encountered a case where *Verilog* module inputs were being assigned to from within the module itself!
I thought for sure this would error out any Verilog simulator, but no, one (at least) lets this pass!
How can this be?!
Isn't this just inviting an "X" tragedy, as soon as something outside the module assigns a different value to the input?
Am I REALLY missing something here?

In case it matters, the module in question came as part of a *behavioral simulation* library provided to us by our foundry.

Comment: Depending on the type of assignment and input declaration it could either be a possibility of 'x' or a possibility of race. linting tools should flag this. Compilers should warn as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Verilog language does not have any rules about the flow of data based on port direction. The SystemVerilog LRM has a section **23.3.3.1 Port coercion** that explicily describes places where inputs can be coerced to output and vice versa. However, Synthesis tools have coding requirements that prevent multiple drivers on the same signal. So if there are drivers from both inside and outside the instatiated module, you *will* get synthesis errors.

SystemVerilog has a number of coding styles that can catch multiple drivers on a signal as part of the simulation flow, so you don't have to wait until you get to synthesis, or use a separate linting tool.

Comment: I agree with Dave, however I'll just add a note that you _may_ get synthesis errors. I had picked up some legacy code from another designer and they had this exact issue. Due to the top level of the synthesis block, it did not error. It wasn't until I ran LEC that I noticed it, and even then it wasn't super obvious.